# angularjs binding keypess using on

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

```
angular.element('#number_of_uses').on('keypress' ,function(e){
      alert(e)
    })
```

can I do something like this? I did not get any error with above code. Hmm want to make sure the input equal to one if the it is empty.

Comment: It would be better to use the Angular directives instead of the jQuery Lite stuff. So use `ng-keypress` on your `number_of_uses` input.

Comment: @Lex this simple thing I do not want to use directive.

Comment: Angular 1.x is all about using directives. `ng-model` is a directive. `ng-click` is a directive. `ng-keypress` is much more simple than the `angular.element` approach you are taking.